# geo django The specified module could not be found

Tags: django, gis, postgis, geodjango

i'm trying to make location based web application with django and sub framework (geodjango) and postgresql - postgis , `windows 10`

i've also installed GDAL through `GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`,geos, and added this line to settings.py file

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\gdal111.dll'
```

and database

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': '...',
    'USER':'....',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PASSWORD':'....',
    'PORT':'5432',

}
}
```

but still getting this error while im trying to `python manage.py makemigrations/migrate`

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

and when i run `python manage.py runserver`  i get this error

> LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.

Comment: Try this - sudo apt-get install -y libgdal-dev

Comment: i use windows and also installed gdal

Answer (score 1):

I put `gdal300.dll` as target and that worked.